# "Read timed out" errors in Orbeon that fail otherwise valid POST submission

Tags: orbeon

I have been observing what appear to be sporadic "Read time out" messages in Orbeon's log (v4.9 running in Tomcat 7.0.59 on Linux) which result in what would other wise be a perfectly health POST submission being returned with an forms-submit-error.

```
2016-01-26 02:56:55,708 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 end opening connection {time (ms): "6010"}
2016-01-26 02:56:55,708 DEBUG XFormsServer  -               end connecting {time (ms): "6011"}
2016-01-26 02:56:55,708 DEBUG XFormsServer  -               start handling result
2016-01-26 02:56:55,708 DEBUG XFormsServer  -               end handling result {time (ms): "0"}
2016-01-26 02:56:55,708 DEBUG XFormsServer  -             end submission {time (ms): "6201"}
2016-01-26 02:56:55,731 ERROR XFormsServer  -             xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Read timed out                                                                                                        |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|http://core-stage.demo.marklogic.com:80/DataCollection/logs/2015-CORE-AR-SH.xml   |                              |    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException                                                                            |
```

Having combed through the orbeon logs I see that POST requests with:

```
end opening connection {time (ms): "6010"}
end connecting {time (ms): "6011"}
start handling result
end handling result {time (ms): "0"}
end submission {time (ms): "6201"}
xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
...
```

i.e. six or more seconds result in the time-out but below six seconds:

```
end opening connection {time (ms): "5563"}
deserializing to mutable instance
end connecting {time (ms): "5565"}
start handling result
...
```

it seems quite happy.

- Am I right to assume that this time-out occurs because Orbeon is not able to read the whole request in a reasonable amount of time e.g. six seconds?
- Is there a six second time-out on reading a POST submission in Orbeon and if so, is it configurable?
- Under what circumstances will Orbeon time-out on a POST submission?

There was a similar thread in 2009 on [discuss.orbeon.com](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Periodic-refresh-causing-server-quot-Read-timed-out-quot-td45294.html)

Comment: AFAIK, Orbeon Forms doesn't set any timeout on HTTP connections. What is the user observed behavior when this happens? Can you reproduce this by instead doing a POST to http://httpbin.org/ `/delay` service? I'm asking as this would be a way of testing whether you have timeout configured, as even if not set by Orbeon Forms itself, it could come from somewhere else.

Comment: The user sees an error message via the `xf:message` associated with the `forms-submit-error` event that is despatched by the response whose processing timed-out. The other aspect of the submission process is that the request goes via MarkLogic so it may be that MarkLogic's resending of the request that is stopping/failing/timing-out in some way and Orbeon cannot finish processing and throws the exception.

Comment: What do you mean by "MarkLogic's resending of the request"? Also, if it does through MarkLogic, do you have some way to add some logging at that level to see what is send and returned by MarkLogic for those requests?